# How to merge same field for two records in single sql table

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

Am maintaining a data base named CustomerInfo for multiple employees, whenever a customer contacts me am inserting that customer details into the table.... If the same customer calls again and again, am inserting as new record with only id number and product for which the call made is differed...

If i search table with id it returns only one record, but if i search with phone number or email id it may give multiple record, Now i want the return record as follows

```
Customer Name, Phone Number, Email Id, product1,product2,...
```

Is it possible to do like this in SQL...?
If so please explain me...

Comment: Why tag it with Java?  How are you searching by ID?

Comment: You realize of course that more than one person can have the same phone number, right?  In any event, you should look at normalizing your database.  If you don't know what that means, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: @DanBracuk Please refer some book....

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with aggregation and `group_concat()`:

```
select CustomerName, PhoneNumber, EmailId, group_concat(product)
from CustomerInfo
group by CustomerName, PhoneNumber, EmailId;
```

That said, your database should have at least two tables.  One for customers with their contact information.  And another, `CustomerProducts` for the product information.  This is called "normalization" and you should be familiar with this concept if you are using relational databases.  There are many good explanations online.